# Javascript function is not changing image on hover of a div

Tags: javascript, html

This is very silly question but i am new to javascript. i want to move my slider on hover on a specific div. i Made a function but it is not working.
Can anybody help me out for it.
My code is here:-

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var image1=new Image()
    image1.src="images/banner_about.png"
     var image2=new Image() 
    image2.src="images/pregnancyclub_banner.jpg"
     var image3=new Image()
    image3.src="images/Refer-a-Friend-banner.jpg"


    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function move() 
    {

     document.slide.src=image2.src;
     }}
     </script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <a href="#" onClick=""="move()"
        onMouseOut="document.slide.src=image1.src;">
     <div id="yash" style="position:absolute;            background:#FF0000;height:20px;width:20px;margin-right:200px;margin-top:200px;">
     </div>
     </a>

      <div id="slider">
       <img src="images/banner_about.png" name="slide" border="0" width="100%"   height="100%" />
       </div>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your function with this:

```
function move() 
{

 document.getElementsByName('slide')[0].src=image2.src;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy! it worked like charm for me. I have another question. Can i give animations and effects in these Slides? If yes, than how?Please give me example of it.

Comment: Yes, you can. See this tutorial: http://javascript.info/tutorial/animation (I think you don't want to use jQuery?)

Comment: i want to move image from left to right very slowly. How can i do it in this code?

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code, first remove them and try it,

**1)** remove extra curly from below code  `}`

```
function move() {
     document.slide.src=image2.src;
}
```

**2)** The `move()`is not intialized in correct way

should be

```
 <a href="#" onClick="move()".....
```

intead of

```
 <a href="#" onClick=""="move()"....
```